# How to attract parent_id to hidden input codeigniter/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have a select drop down on my form, of my categories from my database

**Question:** When I select a category from my select form, if it has a parent id
how am I able to **attract** that parent id to the **hidden input value** on my form.

**Controller**

```
<?php

class Pages extends Admin_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('admin/catalog/model_catalog_pages');

        $data['page_categories'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_pages->get_category();

        foreach ($results as $result) {

            if ($result['parent_id']) {

                // If Child Category

                $data['page_categories'][] = array(
                    'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                    'parent_id' => $result['parent_id'],
                    'name' => $this->model_catalog_pages->get_parent_name($result['parent_id']) .' &gt; '. $result['name']
                );

            } else {

                // If Parent Category

                $data['page_categories'][] = array(
                    'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                    'parent_id' => $result['parent_id'],
                    'name' => $result['name']
                );
            }
        }       

        $this->load->view('template/catalog/page_form_view', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

**View**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-page" class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Categories</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select class="form-control" name="category_select" id="category_select">
    <?php foreach ($page_categories as $category) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="category_parent_id" name="category_parent_id" value="" />
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would tackle this problem is to add a data attribute to the dropdown menu options and then use some javascript to detect if its present. Try this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_select" id="category_select">
    <?php foreach ($page_categories as $category) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>" <?php echo isset($category['parent_id']?'data-parent_id="'.$category['parent_id]'"':'';?>><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="category_parent_id" name="category_parent_id" value="" />
```

The Javascript:

```
var dd = document.getElementById('category_select');
var hidden = document.getElementById('category_parent_id');
dd.addEventListener('change',selectParent,false);
function selectParent(){
    for(var i in dd.options){
        if(dd.options[i].selected == true){
            if(dd.options[i].dataset.parentid){
                hidden.value = dd.options[i].dataset.parentid
            }else{
                hidden.value = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
selectParent();
```

Here is a fiddle of the javscript doing its thing, I've used type='text' input field in the fiddle to demonstrate that it works but this the code will still work with type='hidden'
http://jsfiddle.net/cpr63ajb/1/

Edit: I've tweaked the javascript so that when the page loads, it should select whatever is in the dropdown menu by default. This avoids the need of adding a dummy 'please select' option. (old JS code available here: http://jsfiddle.net/cpr63ajb).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ben Broadley working now.

By his way on the option i added data-parentid and echoed parend id so looks like this now

`data-parentid="<?php echo $category['parent_id'];?>`

And added his script all working

```
<?php

class Pages extends Admin_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('admin/catalog/model_catalog_pages');

        $data['page_categories'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_pages->get_category();

        foreach ($results as $result) {

            if ($result['parent_id']) {

                // If Child Category

                $data['page_categories'][] = array(
                    'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                    'parent_id' => $result['parent_id'],
                    'name' => $this->model_catalog_pages->get_parent_name($result['parent_id']) .' &gt; '. $result['name']
                );

            } else {

                // If Parent Category

                $data['page_categories'][] = array(
                    'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                    'parent_id' => $result['parent_id'],
                    'name' => $result['name']
                );
            }
        }       

        $this->load->view('template/catalog/page_form_view', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

View

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-page" class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Categories</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select class="form-control" name="category_select" id="category_select">
    <?php foreach ($page_categories as $category) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>" data-parentid="<?php echo $category['parent_id'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="category_parent_id" name="category_parent_id" value="" />
</div>
</div>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dd = document.getElementById('category_select');
var hidden = document.getElementById('category_parent_id');
dd.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    for(var i in dd.options){
        if(dd.options[i].selected == true){
            if(dd.options[i].dataset.parentid){
                hidden.value = dd.options[i].dataset.parentid
            }else{
                hidden.value = "";
            }
        }
    }

},0);
</script>
```